# Another ways instead of using any loop function to build a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Here is my code:

```
$matches = Array(80246, 81227, 18848, 15444, 88114, 11488);

$info = Array("id" => "3", "url" => "http://example.com/");


function get_matches($matches, $info)
{
    foreach ($matches as $match)
    {
        $row['target'] = $match;
        $row['id'] = $info['id'];
        $scr_matches[] = $row;
    }

    return $scr_matches;
}


$scr_matches = get_matches($matches, $info);

print_r($scr_matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [target] => 80246
            [id] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [target] => 81227
            [id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [target] => 18848
            [id] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [target] => 15444
            [id] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [target] => 88114
            [id] => 3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [target] => 11488
            [id] => 3
        )

)
```

I'm looking for other solutions instead of using any loop functions (foreach in my case) and give me the same output, i also tried to use `array_map()` but i couldn't get it to work and give me the output that i expect, any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I absolutely don't understand why you want to avoid `foreach` as it is the **simpliest** and **most readable** approach for writing code. But for example you can:

```
$matches = Array(80246, 81227, 18848, 15444, 88114, 11488);
$info = Array("id" => "3", "url" => "http://example.com/");
$iid = $info['id'];

$scr_matches = array_reduce($matches, function($t, $v) use ($iid) {
    $t[] = [
        'target' => $v,
        'id' => $iid,
    ];
    return $t;
}, []);
```

With `array_map`:

```
$matches = Array(80246, 81227, 18848, 15444, 88114, 11488);
$info = Array("id" => "3", "url" => "http://example.com/");
$iid = $info['id'];

$scr_matches = array_map(function($v) use ($iid) {
    return [
        'target' => $v,
        'id' => $iid,
    ];
}, $matches);
```

These and any other solutions will still use looping over array, though this process will be hidden under the hood.